# Displaying certain parts of reviews - Magento

Tags: magento, review, testimonials

I only want to display certain fields from the review block on my Magento product pages, is there a way to do this without using *display:none* or otherwise tampering with styles?  I am trying to make my own *testimonial block* on the product page but I'm unsure how to dissect the reviews block.

Answer (score 0):

The reviews are displayed from here app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/review/product/view/list.phtml
All you have to do is remove anything you don't want from here